# JQuery getJSON Each

Tags: jquery, json

Using the **json** selector tool I can find the selection I want...

```
['result'][0]['creator’][‘box_id']
```

But I'm not sure how to write the **JQuery** to get all the **box_id**

This is my attempt but it fails

```
$.each(data.result[0]creator.box_id, function(key,value){
```

this works

```
$.each(data.result[0], function(key,value){
```

So I think its how im entering the `creator.box_id` part?

Thanks in advance!

JSON

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "box_id": "d20fbaa60f1d4b4dbd8263e430286f5c",
        "start_at": 1441072565094,
        "current_at": 1441078127720
    },
    {

        "box_id": "33bb7b1f359c429ab07b677ae78dfc00",
        "start_at": 1441076404685,
        "current_at": 1441078127748,

    },
```

etc etc

I tried adding..

```
$.each(data.result[0].creator.box_id, function(key,value){
```

and i get a new error in the console...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in         dadfd1f55453441cb059710ece0d1a6bs 
@ jquery.js:2n.extend.each 
@ jquery.js:2(anonymous function) 
@ content.js:34n.Callbacks.j 
@ jquery.js:2n.Callbacks.k.fireWith 
@ jquery.js:2x 
@ jquery.js:4n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send.b @ jquery.js:4
```

Comment: show the sample json.

Comment: you may be forgot `.` `[0].creator` 
correct is `data.result[0].creator.box_id`??

Comment: when you `$(data.result[0],function())` then it will iterate through your **object array** which are under `data.result[0]`. creator one of your object which is exist in **data.result[0]**, can you give us your JSON example for better clarity?

Comment: Now you have given valid JSON and there is no creator here.

Comment: I missed it out when i was typing the example, I"m sorry I will edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed dot, try this `data.result[0].creator.box_id`.

**UPDATE:**

```js
var data = {
"result": [
    {
        "box_id": "d20fbaa60f1d4b4dbd8263e430286f5c",
        "start_at": 1441072565094,
        "current_at": 1441078127720
    },
    {

        "box_id": "33bb7b1f359c429ab07b677ae78dfc00",
        "start_at": 1441076404685,
        "current_at": 1441078127748,

    }
]};

$.each(data.result, function(key, val) {
  console.log(val.box_id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete explanation:

If you consider below JSON

```
var x = "{"code":200,"result":[{"box_id":"d20fbaa60f1d4b4dbd8263e430286f5c","changedAt":1439575955773}]}";
var y = JSON.parse(x);
```

> y["result"] is your object array, now iterate this with JQuery

```
$.each(y["result"],function(key,value){
                            alert("index"+key);
                            alert("box_id"+value["box_id"]);
                            alert("changedAt"+value["changedAt"])});
```

Hope it's clear and helpful for you.